# How to install Resharper plugin?

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

Although Resharper is great, but how to install plugin for it is not immediately obvious. There is a Resharper Gallery which is based on nuget. But how do I install a plugin? No instructions. Could someone help me out here? I am using the Resharper 8.1 with VS2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. There is an extension manager in the "Resharper" menu. That should do.

Answer (score -2):

If you have plugin DLL locally on your box then run following command:

```
devenv.exe /ReSharper.Plugin PluginName.dll
```

To check if plugin is installed go to Resharper->Options->Plugins menu. 
You might need to provide full path to devenv.exe and to your plugin.

Comment: I tried using this approach, and it said that invalid switch `/ReSharper.Plugin`. I used R# v9.0 update 1.